# PDO декодировать данные из json поля и вывести как массив

Tags: mysql, json, pdo

Требуется помощь по PDO. Необходимо получить записи из базы данных, где есть одного json поле - rate, которое нужно декодировать перед выводом в массив.

json поле rate содержит данные по типу `{"in":1,"out":5}`

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, c, rate, min FROM rates')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

получаю массив

```
Array ( [2] => Array ( [c] => 1.12910000 [rate] => {"in": 2, "out": 1} [min] => 10 ) [3] => Array ( [c] => 64.80490000 [rate] => {"in": 1, "out": 2} [min] => 5 )
```

нужно чтобы json данные из rate были декодированы перед выводом.

пробовал так, но не получается...

```
$stmt['rate'] = json_decode($stmt['rate']);
```

Comment: У вас многомерный масив. Например для первого елемента вашего примера нужно декодировать так `$stmt[2]['rate'] = json_decode($stmt[2]['rate']);`. В целом пройдитесь цыклом по масиву и декодируйте значения.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Пробую через цикл по массиву

$arr = array();
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, c, rate, min FROM rates');
while($row = stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE)) {
$row['id']['rate'] = json_decode($row['id']['rate']);
$arr[] = $row;
}
print_r($arr);

но все равно не декодирует поле rate и выводит данные json в массиве. что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, c, rate, min FROM rates')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);

$decode_arr = [];

foreach($stmt as $pos => $value){
    $value[rate] = (array) json_decode($value[rate]);
    $decode_arr[$pos] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый Dmitriy! Я очень признателен вам, но у нас режим вывода по уникальному полю id (в базе два значения - 2 и 3) - а у нас это не учитывается... пытаюсь получить результат через print_r($decode_arr);получаю Array ( [0] => Array ( [с] => 1.12910000 [rate] => Array ( [in] => 2 [out] => 1 ) [min] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [c] => 64.80490000 [rate] => Array ( [in] => 1 [out] => 2 ) [min] => 5 )    т.е. удалось декодировать json поле rate, но индексация идет с 0, а должна быть по id первый Array ( [2].... затем  [3]       Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Внес правки, теперь значения id должны сохранятся

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо. Вот теперь всё отлично! Во всем разобрался, вот только хотел уточнить, что значит в коде (array) ?

Comment: json_decode - возвращает объект, а вам нужен массив поэтому пишем (array) чтобы объект преобразовать в массив